# update current date and time to db using sql from Java code

Tags: java, sql, date, time

i have a table "queue_in_progress" whose structure is like the following :

[image]

I want to update the DATE_TIME_TOKEN_TAKEN  , CE_PK , Service_status  of the table . For this , I have the following code :

```
    String sqlQuery = "UPDATE queue_in_progress\n"  +
                 "SET CE_PK="+ce_pk+" ,SERVICE_STATUS=1 \n"  +
                 "WHERE CATEGORY_PK="+Category_PK+" AND TOKEN_NO="+ Token_PK+" "
                    + " AND SERVICE_COUNTER="+service_counter+" AND SERVICE_CENTER_PK="+service_center+" ;";

java.util.Date utilDate = new Date();  // Convert it to java.sql.Date
java.sql.Date date = new java.sql.Date(utilDate.getTime());

PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(sqlQuery);
                    stmt.setDate(1, date);
                    success = stmt.executeUpdate();

 But the success flag is returning -1 and the table is not updated . What is the problem ? What can I do to fix this problem ?
```

Comment: I don't see a bind parameter in your query.

Comment: What do you want to mean by this statement ?

Comment: What would `stmt.setDate(1, date);` statement do? And I would also suggest you to review the query.

Comment: Can u do System.out.println(sqlQuery) before prepared statement and show us the result!! If u don't mind!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see `DATE_TIME_TOKEN_TAKEN=?` in your query (the bind parameter), I think you wanted

```
String sqlQuery = "UPDATE queue_in_progress SET DATE_TIME_TOKEN_TAKEN=?, "
        + "CE_PK=" + ce_pk
        + ", SERVICE_STATUS=1 WHERE CATEGORY_PK="
        + Category_PK
        + " AND TOKEN_NO="
        + Token_PK
        + " AND SERVICE_COUNTER="
        + service_counter + " AND SERVICE_CENTER_PK=" + service_center;
```

Comment: I want that "DATE_TIME_TOKEN_TAKEN" field should be filled with current system time . What can I do to do that ?

Comment: `stmt.setDate(1, new java.sql.Date());` or you modify your query (but the precise syntax depends on your database).

Comment: stmt.setDate(1, new java.sql.Date()) exists in my code . So where is the problem ?

Comment: Start over. Is the row now updating? If so, it is getting the current system date.

Answer (score 0):

OR if you want `DATE_TIME_TOKEN_TAKEN` to ALWAYS hold Current Time value, you can Set it on your Database side, no need to set it in your code.

```
ALTER TABLE queue_in_progress
MODIFY DATE_TIME_TOKEN_TAKEN DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```